# Grails gorm mongodb delete in chunks

Tags: grails, grails-orm, gorm-mongodb

How to delete documents from MongoDB in chunks using gorm?
`findAll` followed by delete will not work because of the huge number of documents returned by findAll. It results in heap issue.

I was hoping to send a native mongo db command using Domain class.
I do not want to fetch all the domain objects into JVM heap and then iterate to delete them. Instead I want to send the criteria of the deletion to mongo, and let it handle the deletion.

Any pointers on the batch deletion using low level queries? or any other means?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the mongo-gorm/gmongo's `low-level` API:

```
SomeDomain.collection.remove( [ date:[ $lt:now ] ] )
```

see [user guide](http://grails.github.io/grails-data-mapping/mongodb/manual/guide/4.%20Low-level%20API.html) for details

Comment: Used a flavour of this. Please see my answer below.

Comment: the 'flavor' is not groovy enough )

Comment: my answer is really about the use of mongo inside a grails app with groovy

Comment: It will not delete things in chunks.

Comment: what would it do instead? :)

Comment: Read this :http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/Bulk/#ordered-operations thanks!

Comment: `remove()` deletes all docs (unless `justOne:true`) that satisfy the query. This is exactly what the OP wanted to do. What else are you talking about?!

Comment: accepting this as its more groovier than my response :)

Answer (score 0):

Below approach helped to send the delete command to MongoDB.

```java
MyDomainClass.collection.remove(new BasicDBObject("property", valueOrCondition))
```

My requirement was to delete all documents which are older than a given data. Below code helped me achieve what I wanted:

```java
MyDomainClass.collection.remove(new BasicDBObject("createdDate", new BasicDBObject('$lt', createdDateCutOff)))
```